# i have a list box which loads a column from ms access but how to remove repeated words in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a list box that loads data from MS ACCESS but i want to filer the words..

The O/P of listbox

bmw
yamaha
suzuki
audi
bmw
suzuki

This is how it dipsplays but actually i want like this

bmw
yamaha
suzuki
audi

How can we do this in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SQl statement to load the data you can use the distinct keyword:

Select distinct name from mytable